# bytesAvailable() returns value but waitForReadyRead() returns false why?

Tags: qt, sockets

`socket->bytesAvailable()` returns the number of bytes available but the `waitForReadyRead()` returns `false`. This happens only when the value of the value of the `bytesAvailable()` matches my expected value.

```
int rem_bytes=length+2;//if rem_bytes=4000
while(socket->bytesAvailable()<=rem_bytes)
    {


        if (!socket->waitForReadyRead(10000))//if socket->bytesAvailable()==rem_bytes it times out
        {
            qDebug() << "waitForReadyRead() timed out";
            return;
        }

       byteArray.append(socket->read(rem_bytes));

           if(byteArray.size()==length+2)
           {
               for(int j=0;j<length;j++)
                   newarray.append(byteArray[j]);

               fileobj.write(newarray);
               fileobj.flush();
               newarray.clear();
               byteArray.clear();
               break;
           }

           else
           {
               rem_bytes -=byteArray.size();
           }


   }

    Send();
  }
```

The `waitForReadyRead()` times out only when `bytesAvailable()==rem_bytes` in the while loop. In other cases it executes well. I have checked with different data sizes even then the problem remains the same. Kindly point out where I have gone wrong.

Comment: Can you also print out what you're saying, `qDebug() << "waitForReadyRead() timed out, available = " << socket->bytesAvailable();` so there is no doubt that socket->bytesAvailable() isn't 0 or something else ?

Comment: @ nos I have already checked that, but not included here. I returns a value (rem_bytes) and not 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I really don't know what you expect. You should only invoke `waitForReadyRead` if you think you'll get more data. A `false` return value simply means to no new data arrived, not that there's nothing to read.

Your condition should be:

```
while(socket->bytesAvailable()<rem_bytes)
```

When you've got as many bytes available as you expect to receive, you must not wait, since the `readyRead` signal won't ever fire.